# Discord UI Button (Interaction Failed)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-buttons

I'm not sure why but can't get this to work no matter what I try, just trying to do a test button to see if I can do it, and I'll I get is interaction Fail.

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    view = View()
    view.add_item(Button(label="test", custom_id="test"))

    message = await ctx.send("Click the button below to test!", view=view)

    @bot.listen("button_click")
    async def on_button_click(interaction):
        try:
            if interaction.component.custom_id == "test":
                response = "Test worked!"
                await interaction.response.send_message(response)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    try:
        await bot.wait_for("button_click", check=lambda inter: inter.message.id == message.id, timeout=15.0)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        await message.edit(content="Timed out.")
        view.clear_items()
    except Exception as e:
        await ctx.send(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

I keep getting interaction failed with this test command with the discord ui buttons, no matter what I try it's not working correct the command works, but the button doesn't just says interaction failed.

Answer (score 0):

`on_button_click` doesn't exist. You can't just make up a random event and assume the library will fire it. Read the [official examples](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/examples/views) that show how to attach a callback to a button.

Comment: Um, yes it does lol https://docs.discord4py.dev/en/latest/additions.html#on_button_click

Comment: @allencody_ those are not the discord.py docs, the navbar very clearly says `discord.py-message-components`..................